# libuvc_camera vs. libuvc

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to compile libuvc_camera with current (git) version of libuvc. The libuvc library is released into ROS but I can't find any catkin package for it. There is release repository (https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc-release) and repository with non-ROS library (https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc). Do I miss something? How can I compile it as a ROS package - to overlay released version (/opt/ros/indigo/share/libuvc)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199242/libuvc_camera-vs.-libuvc/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I missed that release repository has more branches - there is release/indigo/libuvc branch which contains catkin package.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1